# Clipboard not found in UWP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently working on a project consisting of one program which tracks faces (which we got from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicFaceTracking), which is a Windows Universal App and our program, which is supposed to get the number of faces recognized and reacting appropriately.

I thought about copying the number of faces detected by the facetracking program to the clipboard and just reading it from the program. 
The problem I have (which might actually be really simple) is that I can't seem to get to the Clipboard Class from within the UWP app. 
Using `OpenClipboard(NULL)` or similar but I always get the error that the IDentifier is not found, no mater which header I include or not...

Can anyone give me a clue what to do? Or maybe a better alternative to transfer that one tiny `int` from one program to the other?

Thanks in advance.

janine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UWP applications you should use [Clipboard class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard).

`OpenClipboard` is an old Win32 API that is only available to desktop applications as mentioned at [corresponding MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Minimum supported client  Windows 2000 Professional [**desktop apps only**]